# What is the best way to make static react native pages look the same across devices?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-paper

I'm working on a small react native application. One of the pages is static and consists of lots of pictures and text. I'm using react-native-paper, where each card has a title and picture, and sometimes a paragraph of text.

I'm running into an issue where the pictures will look fine on my Pixel 4XL, but will be cut off on my iPad Pro. I tried following a guide that would take into account which device was being used and scaling the react-native-paper card and cover (the picture itself) to fit, but it doesn't seem to be acting the way I want it to. All cards have the **cardTest** style, and all covers have the **pictureTest** style.

[First card on iPad Pro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfzyA.jpg)

[First card on Pixel 4XL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdUqg.jpg)

```
const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("window");

const guidelineBaseWidth = 350;
const guidelineBaseHeight = 680;

const scale = size => (width / guidelineBaseWidth) * size;
const verticalScale = size => (height / guidelineBaseHeight) * size;
const moderateScale = (size, factor = 0.5) => size + (scale(size) - size) * factor;
.
.
.
cardTest: {
    width: moderateScale(550),
    height: verticalScale(275),
    padding: scale(10)
  },

pictureTest: {
    width: moderateScale(380, 0.3),
    height: verticalScale(230, 0.5)
  },
```

Any help or general feedback would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to setup the width/height variables to be dynamically responsive for the screen size. The easiest way to do that is to use percent based values for the width/height, e.g. `width: '60%'` to take up 60% of the device's screen width. There are some caveats to this approach though. The rendering of percent based widths can look VERY different between small/large devices.

Another method to achieve this type of layout is to use flexbox. Similar to CSS flexbox, React Native has a system for doing flex layouts. You can read more about it [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flexbox). Combining flexbox with percent based element sizes is probably your best bet for consistency across devices.